# Extend clearance for a 28mm tire

Tags: road-bike, tire

I tried upgrading to some 28mm but as you can see clearance is very tight. In some spots, the tire doesn't fully clear the brake (Tektro R350). The fork barely has enough clearance.

Is it worth trying to get an extra mm or 2 with a different brake? I searched around and I saw Tektro has long-arm options, but it's not the arm-length that's limiting, it's the shape of the top of the brake itself. Any brake recommendations? (already read [this post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6420/how-to-get-more-tire-clearance-with-caliper-brakes) - I'm hoping to stick with Tektro or any other fairly inexpensive option, and I only need the front brake.)

[image: Clearance]

Comment: How dedicated are you to 700c sized wheels? Do you and your bike have a committed long-term relationship? What sort of budget is involved?

Comment: @WTHarper main thing that matters to me is low-cost and getting it ridable today. That's why I think I'm going to just get some 25mm's.

Comment: Look for a donor bike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's space you could look into mounting your brake behind the fork crown.

Because your forks are (I assume) raked then there will be more clearance for the tire on the back side of the crown.

If you do turn a front brake backwards, be sure to swap the pads around so they're still facing the right way.

http://www.tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=79&sortname=Brake&sort=1&fid=2

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. I think I'm going to just take the tires back and get some 25mm though.

Answer (score 2):

```
In some spots, the tire doesn't fully clear the brake
```

I take this to mean that the wheel isn't straight, and the tire rubs at certain points in its rotation. If you spend some time truing the wheel, you might be able to get it straight enough that it doesn't rub. The advantage of this approach: you don't have to buy anything.

Another option: keep an eye out for cheap cyclocross forks with cantilever mounts.

Comment: It's not rubbing on the sides, only in a few spots on the very top, against the arch in the brake. Does that still mean it's a truing problem?

Comment: If it rubs at every point in the wheel's rotation, then there's nothing to be done - the tire's just too big. But if the wheel is out of round, then yes, this is absolutely a truing problem. Truing means that you make the rim as close to a perfect circle as possible - you eliminate both the side-to-side and up-and-down wobble.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I always thought truing only had to do with side-to-side but that makes more sense.